How to enforce angle constraint during optimization in Python kinematic model?
I'm working on a Python optimization problem where I need to enforce a constraint that the angle between two vectors (formed by points JG and LA) must be less than 160 degrees. This constraint should be respected during the optimization process, particularly for the initial position of the points. However, despite implementing a penalty-based approach and using the SLSQP optimizer with an explicit nonlinear constraint, the angle is not being respected. I'm looking for advice on how to improve my code to ensure that this constraint is strictly enforced throughout the optimization.
I defined a penalty function that adds a large penalty to the objective function if the angle exceeds 160 degrees during the initial position optimization.
I also tried using a NonlinearConstraint with the SLSQP optimizer to explicitly enforce the constraint.
Despite these efforts, the optimization results still sometimes violate the angle constraint, particularly in the initial configuration.
I expected the optimization process to strictly enforce the angle constraint, ensuring that the angle between points JG and LA remains below 160 degrees, especially for the initial position.
The distance dist_AI is calculated after determining the initial positions of the points, based on the optimal angles for BL and GJ, along with the initial guess for the distances (dist_BF, dist_FG, dist_GJ, etc.). Here’s the specific part of the code where dist_AI is computed:
points_initial = compute_points(angle_BL_opt, angle_GJ_opt, *initial_guess) dist_AI = np.sqrt((points_initial['A'][0] - points_initial['I'][0])**2 + (points_initial['A'][1] - points_initial['I'][1])**2)

Thanks to your help, by modifying the initial guesses I have now the following code that respects the 160° angle constraint :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, minimize, minimize_scalar, NonlinearConstraint

# Helper functions
def deg_to_rad(angle_deg):
    return angle_deg * np.pi / 180

def rad_to_deg(angle_rad):
    return angle_rad / (np.pi / 180)

def calculate_distance_CE(angle_BL_deg, dist_CE_desired):
    angle_BL = deg_to_rad(angle_BL_deg)
    points = {
        'A': (0, 0),
        'B': (-60, -255),
        'C': (-4, -669.5)
    }
    dist_BL = 2110
    points['L'] = (points['B'][0] + dist_BL * np.cos(angle_BL), points['B'][1] + dist_BL * np.sin(angle_BL))
    dist_BD = 1179.5
    points['D'] = (points['B'][0] + dist_BD * np.cos(angle_BL), points['B'][1] + dist_BD * np.sin(angle_BL))
    dist_BF = 1663
    points['F'] = (points['B'][0] + dist_BF * np.cos(angle_BL), points['B'][1] + dist_BF * np.sin(angle_BL))
    angle_DE = angle_BL + np.pi / 2
    dist_DE = 30
    points['E'] = (points['D'][0] + dist_DE * np.cos(angle_DE), points['D'][1] + dist_DE * np.sin(angle_DE))
    if points['E'][1] <= points['D'][1]:
        points['E'] = (points['D'][0] - dist_DE * np.cos(angle_DE), points['D'][1] - dist_DE * np.sin(angle_DE))
    dist_CE = np.sqrt((points['C'][0] - points['E'][0])**2 + (points['C'][1] - points['E'][1])**2)
    return dist_CE - dist_CE_desired

def adjust_GJ(angle_GJ_deg, angle_BL_deg, dist_vars):
    dist_BF, dist_FG, dist_GJ, dist_GH, dist_HI, dist_JK = dist_vars
    angle_BL = deg_to_rad(angle_BL_deg)
    angle_GJ = deg_to_rad(angle_GJ_deg)
    points = {
        'A': (0, 0),
        'B': (-60, -255),
        'C': (-4, -669.5)
    }
    dist_BL = 2110
    points['L'] = (points['B'][0] + dist_BL * np.cos(angle_BL), points['B'][1] + dist_BL * np.sin(angle_BL))
    dist_BD = 1179.5
    points['D'] = (points['B'][0] + dist_BD * np.cos(angle_BL), points['B'][1] + dist_BD * np.sin(angle_BL))
    points['F'] = (points['B'][0] + dist_BF * np.cos(angle_BL), points['B'][1] + dist_BF * np.sin(angle_BL))
    angle_DE = angle_BL + np.pi / 2
    dist_DE = 30
    points['E'] = (points['D'][0] + dist_DE * np.cos(angle_DE), points['D'][1] + dist_DE * np.sin(angle_DE))
    if points['E'][1] <= points['D'][1]:
        points['E'] = (points['D'][0] - dist_DE * np.cos(angle_DE), points['D'][1] - dist_DE * np.sin(angle_DE))
    angle_GF = angle_BL + np.pi / 2
    points['G'] = (points['F'][0] + dist_FG * np.cos(angle_GF), points['F'][1] + dist_FG * np.sin(angle_GF))
    if points['G'][1] <= points['F'][1]:
        points['G'] = (points['F'][0] - dist_FG * np.cos(angle_GF), points['F'][1] - dist_FG * np.sin(angle_GF))
    points['J'] = (points['G'][0] + dist_GJ * np.cos(angle_GJ), points['G'][1] + dist_GJ * np.sin(angle_GJ))
    if points['J'][1] <= points['G'][1]:
        points['J'] = (points['G'][0] - dist_GJ * np.cos(angle_GJ), points['G'][1] - dist_GJ * np.sin(angle_GJ))
    points['H'] = (points['G'][0] + dist_GH * np.cos(angle_GJ), points['G'][1] + dist_GH * np.sin(angle_GJ))
    if points['H'][1] <= points['G'][1]:
        points['H'] = (points['G'][0] - dist_GH * np.cos(angle_GJ), points['G'][1] - dist_GH * np.sin(angle_GJ))
    angle_IH = angle_GJ + np.pi / 2
    points['I'] = (points['H'][0] + dist_HI * np.cos(angle_IH), points['H'][1] + dist_HI * np.sin(angle_IH))
    if points['I'][0] >= points['H'][0]:
        points['I'] = (points['H'][0] - dist_HI * np.cos(angle_IH), points['H'][1] - dist_HI * np.sin(angle_IH))
    def equations_K(vars, L, J):
        x, y = vars
        eq1 = (x - L[0])**2 + (y - L[1])**2 - 313.41**2
        eq2 = (x - J[0])**2 + (y - J[1])**2 - dist_JK**2
        return [eq1, eq2]
    initial_guess1 = (points['L'][0] + 500, points['L'][1] + 500)
    initial_guess2 = (points['L'][0] - 500, points['L'][1] - 500)
    solution1 = fsolve(equations_K, initial_guess1, args=(points['L'], points['J']), xtol=1e-1)
    solution2 = fsolve(equations_K, initial_guess2, args=(points['L'], points['J']), xtol=1e-1)
    if np.allclose(solution1, solution2):
        initial_guess1 = (points['L'][0] + 1000, points['L'][1] + 1000)
        initial_guess2 = (points['L'][0] - 1000, points['L'][1] - 1000)
        solution1 = fsolve(equations_K, initial_guess1, args=(points['L'], points['J']), xtol=1e-1)
        solution2 = fsolve(equations_K, initial_guess2, args=(points['L'], points['J']), xtol=1e-1)
    K = solution1 if solution1[1] > solution2[1] else solution2
    points['K'] = K
    dist_LM = 500
    angle_ML = np.arctan2(points['L'][1] - K[1], points['L'][0] - K[0]) + deg_to_rad(109.638 + 180)
    points['M'] = (points['L'][0] + dist_LM * np.cos(angle_ML), points['L'][1] + dist_LM * np.sin(angle_ML))
    return abs(points['M'][1] - points['L'][1]), points

def compute_points(angle_BL_opt, angle_GJ_opt, dist_BF, dist_FG, dist_GJ, dist_GH, dist_HI, dist_JK):
    angle_BL = deg_to_rad(angle_BL_opt)
    angle_GJ = deg_to_rad(angle_GJ_opt)
    points = {
        'A': (0, 0),
        'B': (-60, -255),
        'C': (-4, -669.5)
    }
    dist_BL = 2110
    points['L'] = (points['B'][0] + dist_BL * np.cos(angle_BL), points['B'][1] + dist_BL * np.sin(angle_BL))
    dist_BD = 1179.5
    points['D'] = (points['B'][0] + dist_BD * np.cos(angle_BL), points['B'][1] + dist_BD * np.sin(angle_BL))
    points['F'] = (points['B'][0] + dist_BF * np.cos(angle_BL), points['B'][1] + dist_BF * np.sin(angle_BL))
    angle_DE = angle_BL + np.pi / 2
    dist_DE = 30
    points['E'] = (points['D'][0] + dist_DE * np.cos(angle_DE), points['D'][1] + dist_DE * np.sin(angle_DE))
    if points['E'][1] <= points['D'][1]:
        points['E'] = (points['D'][0] - dist_DE * np.cos(angle_DE), points['D'][1] - dist_DE * np.sin(angle_DE))
    angle_GF = angle_BL + np.pi / 2
    points['G'] = (points['F'][0] + dist_FG * np.cos(angle_GF), points['F'][1] + dist_FG * np.sin(angle_GF))
    if points['G'][1] <= points['F'][1]:
        points['G'] = (points['F'][0] - dist_FG * np.cos(angle_GF), points['F'][1] - dist_FG * np.sin(angle_GF))
    points['J'] = (points['G'][0] + dist_GJ * np.cos(angle_GJ), points['G'][1] + dist_GJ * np.sin(angle_GJ))
    if points['J'][1] <= points['G'][1]:
        points['J'] = (points['G'][0] - dist_GJ * np.cos(angle_GJ), points['G'][1] - dist_GJ * np.sin(angle_GJ))
    points['H'] = (points['G'][0] + dist_GH * np.cos(angle_GJ), points['G'][1] + dist_GH * np.sin(angle_GJ))
    if points['H'][1] <= points['G'][1]:
        points['H'] = (points['G'][0] - dist_GH * np.cos(angle_GJ), points['G'][1] - dist_GH * np.sin(angle_GJ))
    angle_IH = angle_GJ + np.pi / 2
    points['I'] = (points['H'][0] + dist_HI * np.cos(angle_IH), points['H'][1] + dist_HI * np.sin(angle_IH))
    if points['I'][0] >= points['H'][0]:
        points['I'] = (points['H'][0] - dist_HI * np.cos(angle_IH), points['H'][1] - dist_HI * np.sin(angle_IH))
    def equations_K(vars, L, J):
        x, y = vars
        eq1 = (x - L[0])**2 + (y - L[1])**2 - 313.41**2
        eq2 = (x - J[0])**2 + (y - J[1])**2 - dist_JK**2
        return [eq1, eq2]
    initial_guess1 = (points['L'][0] + 500, points['L'][1] + 500)
    initial_guess2 = (points['L'][0] - 500, points['L'][1] - 500)
    solution1 = fsolve(equations_K, initial_guess1, args=(points['L'], points['J']), xtol=1e-1)
    solution2 = fsolve(equations_K, initial_guess2, args=(points['L'], points['J']), xtol=1e-1)
    if np.allclose(solution1, solution2):
        initial_guess1 = (points['L'][0] + 1000, points['L'][1] + 1000)
        initial_guess2 = (points['L'][0] - 1000, points['L'][1] - 1000)
        solution1 = fsolve(equations_K, initial_guess1, args=(points['L'], points['J']), xtol=1e-1)
        solution2 = fsolve(equations_K, initial_guess2, args=(points['L'], points['J']), xtol=1e-1)
    K = solution1 if solution1[1] > solution2[1] else solution2
    points['K'] = K
    dist_LM = 500
    angle_ML = np.arctan2(points['L'][1] - K[1], points['L'][0] - K[0]) + deg_to_rad(109.638 + 180)
    points['M'] = (points['L'][0] + dist_LM * np.cos(angle_ML), points['L'][1] + dist_LM * np.sin(angle_ML))
    return points

def plot_points(points, title):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    for point, coord in points.items():
        plt.plot(coord[0], coord[1], 'o', label=point)
        plt.text(coord[0], coord[1], f" {point}", fontsize=12)
    connections = [
        ('A', 'I'), ('A', 'B'),
        ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'L'),
        ('C', 'E'),
        ('D', 'E'),
        ('F', 'G'),
        ('G', 'J'),
        ('H', 'I'),
        ('J', 'K'),
        ('K', 'L'),
        ('L', 'M')
    ]
    for start, end in connections:
        if start in points and end in points:
            plt.plot([points[start][0], points[end][0]], [points[start][1], points[end][1]], 'k-')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()

def calculate_angle_between_vectors(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    v1 = np.array([p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1]])
    v2 = np.array([p4[0] - p3[0], p4[1] - p3[1]])
    dot_product = np.dot(v1, v2)
    magnitude_v1 = np.linalg.norm(v1)
    magnitude_v2 = np.linalg.norm(v2)
    cos_angle = dot_product / (magnitude_v1 * magnitude_v2)
    angle = np.arccos(cos_angle)
    return rad_to_deg(angle)

def minimize_diff_all(dist_vars, angle_BL_opt, angle_GJ_opt, dist_AI, initial_position=False):
    dist_BF, dist_FG, dist_GJ, dist_GH, dist_HI, dist_JK = dist_vars
    points_initial = compute_points(angle_BL_opt, angle_GJ_opt, dist_BF, dist_FG, dist_GJ, dist_GH, dist_HI, dist_JK)
    diff_initial = abs(points_initial['M'][1] - points_initial['L'][1])
    dist_CE_1300 = 1300
    angle_BL_1300 = minimize_scalar(lambda x: np.abs(calculate_distance_CE(x, dist_CE_1300)), bounds=(0, 360), method='bounded').x
    points_1300 = compute_points(angle_BL_1300, angle_GJ_opt, dist_BF, dist_FG, dist_GJ, dist_GH, dist_HI, dist_JK)
    diff_1300 = abs(points_1300['M'][1] - points_1300['L'][1])
    dist_CE_1550 = 1550
    angle_BL_1550 = minimize_scalar(lambda x: np.abs(calculate_distance_CE(x, dist_CE_1550)), bounds=(0, 360), method='bounded').x
    points_1550 = compute_points(angle_BL_1550, angle_GJ_opt, dist_BF, dist_FG, dist_GJ, dist_GH, dist_HI, dist_JK)
    diff_1550 = abs(points_1550['M'][1] - points_1550['L'][1])
    total_diff = diff_initial + diff_1300 + diff_1550

    # Apply penalty for initial position if angle constraint is violated
    if initial_position:
        angle_JG_LA = calculate_angle_between_vectors(points_initial['J'], points_initial['G'], points_initial['L'], points_initial['A'])
        if angle_JG_LA >= 160:
            total_diff += 1e8  # Large penalty if the angle is not lower than 160 degrees

    return total_diff

# Constraint function
def angle_constraint(dist_vars, angle_BL_opt, angle_GJ_opt):
    dist_BF, dist_FG, dist_GJ, dist_GH, dist_HI, dist_JK = dist_vars
    points = compute_points(angle_BL_opt, angle_GJ_opt, dist_BF, dist_FG, dist_GJ, dist_GH, dist_HI, dist_JK)
    angle_JG_LA = calculate_angle_between_vectors(points['J'], points['G'], points['L'], points['A'])
    return 160 - angle_JG_LA  # This should be greater than 0 for the constraint to be satisfied

dist_CE_desired = 1107

res_BL = minimize_scalar(lambda x: np.abs(calculate_distance_CE(x, dist_CE_desired)), bounds=(0, 360), method='bounded')
angle_BL_opt = res_BL.x
print(f"Optimal angle BL: {angle_BL_opt} degrees")

initial_guess = [1660, 30, 570, 420, 25, 690]
bounds = [(1500, 1900), (-50, 50), (400, 700), (100, 500), (-50, 50), (500, 900)]

# Optimize GJ with angle constraint applied for initial position
res_GJ = minimize_scalar(lambda x: adjust_GJ(x, angle_BL_opt, initial_guess)[0], bounds=(0, 360), method='bounded')
angle_GJ_opt = res_GJ.x
print(f"Optimal angle GJ: {angle_GJ_opt} degrees")

# Calculate the initial points based on the initial guess
points_initial = compute_points(angle_BL_opt, angle_GJ_opt, *initial_guess)

# Check if 'A' and 'I' are present in the points_initial dictionary
if 'A' in points_initial and 'I' in points_initial:
    # Calculate dist_AI based on the initial points
    dist_AI = np.sqrt((points_initial['A'][0] - points_initial['I'][0])**2 + (points_initial['A'][1] - points_initial['I'][1])**2)
    
    # Now proceed with the minimization process
    res = minimize(
        lambda d: minimize_diff_all(dist_vars=d, angle_BL_opt=angle_BL_opt, angle_GJ_opt=angle_GJ_opt, dist_AI=dist_AI, initial_position=True),
        initial_guess,
        bounds=bounds,
        method='SLSQP',
        constraints=[angle_constraint_obj]
    )
    optimized_distances = res.x
    print(f"Optimized distances: {optimized_distances}")
    
    # Continue with your processing using optimized_distances...
    
    # Compute the final points with the optimized distances
    points_final = compute_points(angle_BL_opt, angle_GJ_opt, *optimized_distances)

    angle_JG_LA_initial = calculate_angle_between_vectors(points_final['J'], points_final['G'], points_final['L'], points_final['A'])
    print(f"Initial angle between JG and LA: {angle_JG_LA_initial} degrees")

    if 'K' in points_final:
        # Check the initial criteria
        dist_CE_actual = np.sqrt((points_final['C'][0] - points_final['E'][0])**2 + (points_final['C'][1] - points_final['E'][1])**2)
        my_ly_diff = points_final['M'][1] - points_final['L'][1]

        print(f"CE distance after optimization: {dist_CE_actual} mm")
        print(f"My - Ly after optimization: {my_ly_diff}")

        if np.isclose(dist_CE_actual, dist_CE_desired, atol=1e-2) and np.isclose(my_ly_diff, 0, atol=1e-2):
            print("Initial position criteria are satisfied.")
        else:
            print("Initial position criteria are not satisfied.")

        print("Points after initial setup:")
        for point, coord in points_final.items():
            print(f"{point}: {coord}")
        print(f"Distances: BF={optimized_distances[0]}, FG={optimized_distances[1]}, GJ={optimized_distances[2]}, GH={optimized_distances[3]}, HI={optimized_distances[4]}, JK={optimized_distances[5]}")
        plot_points(points_final, f"Initial setup with CE = {dist_CE_desired} mm")

        # Update for CE = 1300 mm
        dist_CE_desired = 1300
        angle_BL_1300 = minimize_scalar(lambda x: np.abs(calculate_distance_CE(x, dist_CE_desired)), bounds=(0, 360), method='bounded').x
        points_1300 = compute_points(angle_BL_1300, angle_GJ_opt, *optimized_distances)
        angle_JG_LA_1300 = calculate_angle_between_vectors(points_1300['J'], points_1300['G'], points_1300['L'], points_1300['A'])
        print(f"Angle between JG and LA for CE=1300: {angle_JG_LA_1300} degrees")
        if 'K' in points_1300:
            print("Points after updating CE to 1300 mm:")
            for point, coord in points_1300.items():
                print(f"{point}: {coord}")
            print(f"Distances: BF={optimized_distances[0]}, FG={optimized_distances[1]}, GJ={optimized_distances[2]}, GH={optimized_distances[3]}, HI={optimized_distances[4]}, JK={optimized_distances[5]}")
            plot_points(points_1300, f"Updated setup with CE = 1300 mm and fixed AI = {dist_AI} mm")

            # Update for CE = 1550 mm
            dist_CE_desired = 1550
            angle_BL_1550 = minimize_scalar(lambda x: np.abs(calculate_distance_CE(x, dist_CE_desired)), bounds=(0, 360), method='bounded').x
            points_1550 = compute_points(angle_BL_1550, angle_GJ_opt, *optimized_distances)
            angle_JG_LA_1550 = calculate_angle_between_vectors(points_1550['J'], points_1550['G'], points_1550['L'], points_1550['A'])
            print(f"Angle between JG and LA for CE=1550: {angle_JG_LA_1550} degrees")
            if 'K' in points_1550:
                print("Points after updating CE to 1550 mm:")
                for point, coord in points_1550.items():
                    print(f"{point}: {coord}")
                print(f"Distances: BF={optimized_distances[0]}, FG={optimized_distances[1]}, GJ={optimized_distances[2]}, GH={optimized_distances[3]}, HI={optimized_distances[4]}, JK={optimized_distances[5]}")
                plot_points(points_1550, f"Updated setup with CE = 1550 mm and fixed AI = {dist_AI} mm")
    else:
        print("Failed to compute valid points for initial setup.")
else:
    print("Error: Could not find points 'A' and 'I' in the computed points.")

But there is still a criteria that is not working :
The initial position should respect the two following criterias :

CE = 1107 --> Already respected
My-Ly=0 --> Not respected

Do you know how to force this constraint?

The usual problems apply: there are several if statements in your cost functions that produce discontinuity; abs is nondifferentiable; there are nested optimizations; and the initial guess is nonsense because it violates your constraint. So the optimizer is very much set up for failure.

I'm not sure I understand the question - it seems like the angle constraint is being respected. The angle it prints out is less than 160 degrees: "Angle between JG and LA for CE=1550: 0.032641148058719906 degrees" And the graph seems to visually confirm this. https://i.imgur.com/N0oUwK1.png (I removed the other points from this graph to make it visually comprehensible.) Can you clarify what aspect is not working?

@NickODell As you can see here : [link] (https://imgur.com/VXus7hT) the angle we talk about is between JG and BL, and it should be lower than 160° for the first position.
But as you can see here : [link] (https://imgur.com/Ab9M74E) this angle is almost 180° for the first position.

In the following code, the rad_to_deg angle conversion is incorrect:
def deg_to_rad(angle_deg):
    return angle_deg * np.pi / 180

def rad_to_deg(angle_rad):
    return angle_rad * np.pi / 180

It is doing the opposite conversion: converting degrees to radians. This function is used in your angle constraint code, and the effect is that it will always think that the angle is less than 0.05 degrees.
Corrected code for rad_to_deg():
def rad_to_deg(angle_rad):
    return angle_rad / (np.pi / 180)


Or just use np.rad2deg and np.deg2rad.

Thank you for the correction. Unfortunately the results stay the same after modification.
